# Selecting lines with length, C filter

Tags: c, filter

I am writing a filter that should select all lines having a specified length. I ended up having this code, but I don't know how to specify `n`. I mean, `n` (and optionally `m`) should be replaced by a number of lines in command prompt, but I have no idea how to describe it in the code. I thought of `case "%d"`, but from what I know it's not possible to write it like that. That's the code I have so far:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int n;
    int m;
    char line[200];
    while(fgets(line,sizeof(line)/sizeof(char), stdin)!=NULL)
        {
            if(argc>1){
        switch(argv[0][0])
        {
        case 'n':
        strlen(line)==n;
        break;

        case '#n':
        strlen(line)<n;
        break;

        case 'n m':
        strlen(line)>=n && strlen(line)<=m;
        break;

        case 'n#':
        strlen(line) > n;
        break;
    }
    printf("%s\n", line);
          }}
    return 0;
}
```

Your help would mean a lot to me! I don't really know how to make it work anymore.

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is always 1 it's mandated by the c standard, also these are evaluated in an implementation specific way, so it might not be what you expect.

Comment: You may drop switch or check argv[0][0] and argv[0][1]...

Comment: `'n m'` is a string so it should be between `" "` not `' '` !! and keep in mind that `case` in `switch()` block **MUST** be **const-integral-expressions** !! why not using the `if()` statements ??

Comment: **correction**: these in my previous comment referes to multicharacer constants like `'n m'`.

Comment: What do these expression do ? `strlen(line)>=n && strlen(line)<=m;`, `strlen(line)==n;`, `strlen(line) > n;`, `strlen(line) < n;` and also, don't use `strlen()` that way, it's bad from any point of view, first it violates the DRY principle and also is expensive...

Comment: @iharob how am I supposed to use strlen then? well if length of the line is equal to n(some value given by user in cmd) it should print the line, same for other expressions, those were supposed to be "conditions"... I'm new to C so I really try to make it work but I'm aware I can make a lot of mistakes... so if you could explain it simply, it would be amazing!

Comment: @Meninx thanks, I already fixed "n m" in my code, yet I don't know how could I use if() instead of switch... in cmd, I need to write something like filtername.exe 5(for example, I mean the length of line(n)) and how am I supposed to define that fact in the code? I mean, my problem is that I don't know how to make it work that I write some number in cmd and it will be my n...

Comment: @Pauline I didn't understand something : What is the aim of the program ? I think if you answer the question of iharob about the meaning of `strlen()` instructions inside the `switch()` block  we can figure out the problem and help you !

Comment: @Meninx sure, I already did answer in comments! The aim is to read lines from standard input in command prompt and print only those that have specified length. Length is defined by n & m; I should be able to write something along the lines "filtername.exe 10 (n; the length of the string) <file.txt"and I want the program to print from file.txt only lines that are 10 characters long... or more than 10 in case of 10# (n#) etc. Hope it explains it! Sorry for causing confusion...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should parse the command line outside of your loop.  Assuming you are going to require the caller of your program to specify both `n` and `m` on the command line, it's a simple matter of grabbing the first two parameters and converting them to integers, and then loop over your stdard input.  Something like this:

```
/* call this minmax.c */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int n, m, len;
    char line[200];

    if (argc < 3) {
        printf("Must specify min & max line length.");
        return -1;
        }

    n = atoi(argv[1]);
    m = atoi(argv[2]);

    while(fgets(line, 200, stdin) != NULL) {
        len = strlen(line);
        if (len >=n && len <= m)
            printf(line);
        }
    return 0;
    }
```

Assuming you are running on *nix:

```
cc -ominmax minmax.c
```

Then call it with the min and max line lengths

```
./minmax 2 5
```

This will echo back every line you type that is at least 2 characters, but no more then 5.

Comment: Whoops (don't I feel foolish). Edited as you suggested.

Comment: hi, thank you very much, but unfortunately the program crashes when I try to run the code! I checked it three times and added some changes, yet it just won't work. I suppose when I run it, I should write two arguments first, n & m, right? (I mean, I write for example 10 and 4). Then the program crashes. Maybe I'm doing something wrong? I tried adding scanf, but nothing changed.

Comment: Fixed a small typo, and provided examples of how to compile and run.

Comment: thank you! i think it's working well now. I gotta make some more changes, but I got the general idea, thanks! Really. I almost gave up hope it'd work.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand well the aim of your desired program and here is the code :

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h> 

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

        int i=1,n,m; // n and m are the variable which holds 
                     // the limited length 
        if(argc>=3)
        {
          // you need to execute the program with this form
          // program.exe n m <file.txt
            n=atoi(argv[1]); // get the value of n
            m=atoi(argv[2]); // get the value of m
            printf("n=%d   m=%d\n",n,m);
        }
        char line[1000]; // this variable will hold each line of the file 
        while (fgets(line,sizeof(line),stdin)) // fgets used to read                                       
        {                                  //the lines in file till the newline 
            int  length=strlen(line)-1;
             // we decrement the length to get rid of 
             // the newline character
            if (length < n)
            {
                printf("line %d:%s status: < %d\n",i,line,n);
            }
            else if (length==n)
            {
                printf("line %d:%s status: = %d\n",i,line,n);
            }
            else if (length>n && length <=m)
            {
                printf("line %d:%s status: %d < <= %d\n",i,line,n,m);
            }
            else 
            {
                printf("line %d:%s status: > %d\n",i,line,m);
            }
            i++;
        }


    return 0;
}
```

In case the code does not fit to your needs I think it is sufficient    and can be taken as a support for your exact program as it encompasses everything you need !! Hope it helps !!

Comment: Newline might not have been included.

Comment: yep it depends actually on the editor used especially for the last line like vim and gedit !! it depends also on the size of the line if it exceeds the size of the variable he can check it !! as I stated at the end he needs to change the code because I have no idea about the content of the file and which editor he uses !!

Comment: @Meninx I ran this code and added some changes, yet it wasn't working, I think because of the whole opening and closing file thing, I never used it before, so it was hard to me to fit it to what I wanted. But I got the overall idea and used some parts to enhance my old code(goodbye switch!), so thank you very much! Seriously, it was very helpful, especially with the comments. Thanks!

Comment: the opening file is okay ! I deleted it and edited the code ! no problem !!